# Apt-get update stays on 0% [Working] for ever and i cannot install anything anymore

Tags: apt

on my Raspberry with Strecth all of a sudden i cannot run apt-get anymore

It hangs on 0% working for ever.
I'm connected to the internet because i can CURL, ping and everything...

if i try to install something... for instance

```
sudo apt-get install nmap
```

I get, very fast

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nmap
```

Some for `sudo apt-get upgrade`

This is my `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
```

Unluckily i cannot reinstall the SD because the raspberry is in another city and i log via ssh in it...

Everything else looks working good... but i cannot install or update any package

Comment: Try `apt-get clean` and then run `apt-get update` again. Does this have any effect?

Comment: no effect... also `apt-get clean` looks does nothing...

Comment: It isn't a bad sign if there's no output. Could you add what's in `/etc/apt/sources.list` with an [edit]?

Comment: The sources list looks OK. Perhaps take a look at some of the steps [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/498949/642653) and see if they help you at all? Particularly the deleting the package lists and trying to update again might be helpful to you.

Comment: unluckily none of the info in that topic helped me... i'll keep trying...

Comment: Have you tried looking at the `apt` application logs to see if they show any information that may lead you to an understanding of why it's failing?  I believe they are located in `/var/log/apt/*.log` and/or `/var/log/dpkg.log`.  Let us know if you find anything. Good luck!